# Nhibernate 3.2 Mapping By Code - Version (Concurrency)

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to migrate a hbm.xml based nhibernate project to mapping by code. I am having problem getting the Version section working. In the hbm.xml i have:

< version name="Version" column="`Version`" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0"/>

I have tried with the following mapping:

```
        Version(x => x.Version, m =>
        {
            m.Column(c =>
            {
                c.SqlType("Int32");
                c.Name("Version");
            });
            m.Generated(VersionGeneration.Always);
            m.UnsavedValue(0);
            m.Insert(true);
            m.Type(new NHibernate.Type.Int32Type());
        });
```

But nothing seems to produce the same mapping as the original hbm.xml, they all end up without the type="Int32". Has anyone got any ideas how I can do this, or if its supported in 3.2?

Cheers

Update:

See my answer

Comment: Dont be afraid to create an answer that includes the working mapping and flag it as correct. This is perfectly legit on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Toni comment I have changed my mapping to:

```
Version(x => x.Version, mapper =>
        {
            mapper.Generated(VersionGeneration.Never);
            mapper.UnsavedValue(0);
            mapper.Type(new NHibernate.Type.Int32Type());
        });
```

Which prove to work as my original hbm.xml

Answer (score 1):

If the property Version is already type of int32 then that is not inserted into the hbm file. I think the type part is only written into the xml file if the actual types are different. Example (domain entity uses int32 but we want to map it using int64):

```
// in the domain entity
public int RowVersion{get;set;}

//  Mapping
this.Version(x => x.RowVersion, mapper =>
    {
        mapper.Generated(VersionGeneration.Never);
        mapper.UnsavedValue(0);
        mapper.Type(new NHibernate.Type.Int64Type());
    });

// Xml file
<version name="RowVersion" type="Int64" unsaved-value="0" />
```

Comment: Just tried your sujestion but got the following error when saving a model.

`Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of Models.Tester`

Changed the my orginal mapping to just this:

`Version(x => x.Version, mapper => { mapper.Generated(VersionGeneration.Never); mapper.UnsavedValue(0);  mapper.Type(new NHibernate.Type.Int32Type()); });`

And it all worked as it did when using hbm.xml